# HEREDOC error for text inclusion in a mail function

Tags: php, include, heredoc

I am using HEREDOC to include some text into the body of a mail PHP function.

However, I get this error:

"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_SL in..."

The errors refers to the HEREDOC part of the included file:

```
<?php
$message = <<<EOD <html></body>Dear $firstName $lastName,
Sincerely,
Customer Service
EOD;?>
```

Is there any issue with the way I am writing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$message = <<<EOD
    <html><body>Dear {$firstName} {$lastName},
    Sincerely,
    Customer Service
EOD;
?>
```

With heredoc syntax there should be nothing except a new line after the opening identifier `<<<EOD` not even whitespace and you want to wrap your variables in curly braces.  The closing identifier`EOD;` should have no whitespace before it and should be followed by a new line.

[PHP Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$message = <<<EOD
<html></body>Dear $firstName $lastName,
Sincerely,
Customer Service
EOD;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
EOD;?>
```

to

```
EOD;
?>
```

Why?

Quoting from PHP docs:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier
>   must contain no other characters, except possibly a semicolon (;).
>   That means especially that the identifier may not be indented, and
>   there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon